# For invertible $A$, $C$, prove that: $(A^{−1} + B^TC^{−1}B)^{−1}B^TC^{−1} = AB^T(BAB^T + C)^{−1}$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Here's what I have to prove:

For invertible $A$, $C$, prove that:
$$
(A^{−1} + B^TC^{−1}B)^{−1}B^TC^{−1} = AB^T(BAB^T + C)^{−1}.
$$

Here's what I have so far. I couldn't do the proof entirely because I got stuck at some point (marked in red) and I'm asking myself if the problem would have to be constrained more.

I couldn't really see a way to start with the left (or right) side and manipulate it such that I end up with the other side - so i proved it through equivalences (which is kind of ugly).

But maybe there is a way to prove it (and also a better style for proving it). Could you help me with this?

Here's what I've done so far:

[image]

Comment: I think you have to assume that it is invertible, because as you have shown, it can be singular under some cases. Ans in fact the equality only hold iff the matrix is invertible

Comment: Maybe it's easier to prove that $$B^TC^{-1}(BAB^T+C) = (A^{-1}+B^TC^{-1}B)AB^T$$ Then I think you have to work under the assumption that the parentheses are invertible matrices.

Comment: Thanks! This was posed in one of my assignments, so I really think that there must be some property that I'm not seeing that can be exploited (unless it was badly posed). If you may see something just let me know - I don't need to see the full proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the parentheses are in fact invertible, you could multiply both sides with the parentheses to eliminate the inverted parentheses:
$$\begin{aligned}
(A^{−1} + B^TC^{−1}B)^{−1}B^TC^{−1} &= AB^T(BAB^T + C)^{−1}  \\
B^TC^{-1}(BAB^T + C) &= (A^{-1} + B^TC^{-1}B)AB^T \\
B^TC^{-1}BAB^T + B^T &=B^T + B^TC^{-1}BAB^T
\end{aligned}$$